# Render a React component every second

Tags: reactjs

So I'm following the React step-by-step documentation (specifically: https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) since the "make a game" tutorial didn't really work for me and I'm trying to recreate the clock updating every second micro-App. Only, I'm doing it locally so I decided to create a component containing the clock:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <h1>The time is</h1>
                <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

which I imported into index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

setInterval(ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')), 1000);
```

Now index.js should do this, at least as far as I understand it: set an interval of 1000 miliseconds so that every 1000 miliseconds the `ReactDOM.render(component, location)` function fires. Except .... it doesn't work. All I'm trying to do is something like this, but with components, instead of a classical function:

The time is:

*insert local time*

*insert local time* etc.

Comment: There is an example of exactly this on React's main page: https://reactjs.org/#a-stateful-component

Comment: Yeah well, I wanted to use stateless components for simplicity's sake ...

Comment: You can create a state That's getting Current time (new Date();) and the use useEffectHook to rerender every time that's its changing,

Comment: I feel using state to do this would actually more simplistic that trying to achieve it without using state.